# Entire folder missing from home screen

Tags: iphone

A baby, playing with my iphone 5, made a folder disappear.  I don't know if she deleted it or not but if I spotlight one of the apps, it is still on the phone and shows the old folder name.  However, none of the apps that were/are in that folder have icons on the screen and I have to spotlight each of them to start it.  Any ideas for restoring the folder or the individual icons so I can make the folder again?

Comment: What folder on an iPhone?

Comment: Try restarting your phone. This definitely happened on iOS 6 and IIRC a restart fixed it.

Comment: Sync your phone with iTunes and then go to Apps and you could remove the missing apps from the phone, sync, then install them back and they should end up on one of the screens.

Comment: Wow!  You guys are fast!  For Mark, it was a folder I had created, called Health.  It held a number of apps related to exercise and diet.  I tried doing a synch, but since the apps are still installed, nothing changed.  I agree I could uninstall and reinstall and stack them to form a folder again but I would lose TONS of historical data about foods and exercise types I've added.  I just don't understand how the app is still there and I can use them, as I did at the gym this morning, but I can't get their icon to display (sigh).

Comment: Reboot by holding power and home button till you see the Apple. Problem solved.

Comment: If the apps still exist, then the apps are hiding somewhere else on a different page of the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and finally figured out a way to fix it!

There are 2 ways to fix this issue, either via iTunes or on the iPhone.  The iTunes route is quicker and if you have a lot of apps in that missing folder you might not remember all of them and iTunes gives you the full list.

1. Go to iTunes with your iPhone plugged in and click on your phone.
2. Go to the apps tab
3. locate all the apps that where in that folder and remove them.

   I actually removed all the apps except 2 that I didn't want to remove just yet because they had data on them that I didn't want to lose. Interestingly enough after removing all the other apps the 2 apps I didn't remove resurfaced on my phone without the folder.  So quite possibly maybe just try to remove 1 or 2 apps from that folder only and see if the other resurface, which makes this process all that quicker and better.
4. Now reinstall all the apps you removed and they should all reappear back on your phone with out the folder.
5. Make a new folder and put all the apps back in.

Voilà, there you have it!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to get back all your missing applications.
Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset all settings.

Let the phone Reset all.

You will not lose your data. All you need to re-enter Wifi codes.
Good luck.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved . Goto settings, Genral, Reset , reset a settings . Wait until device restart , you do not lose any data and all your applications are back

Answer (score 0):

Go to a random folder. Pull out all the apps. It should resurface. 
Alternatively, move all folders to a new screen and then pull the apps out of one. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

All this answers are terribly overcomplicated.

I had this problems several times (with apps and folders disappearing) and solved it by simply restarting my iPhone.